# Allowing file-transfer to use sftp or ssh?

Tags: 7, files

I have my own dev-server that I installed with Ubuntu 11.04. When I set it up, I was fairly new to the whole "server thing", so I'm not sure that I set up everything 100% up to industry standards.

The problem I am having, is that trying to automatically update things almost never works when using drupal's UI.

I usually got around this, by just ssh-ing into my server, and using drush to update everything.

The problem now, however, is, that instead of updating the site, I am trying to install "apps" (not modules), and I am not sure how to do this with drush. (plus I want to figure out how to fix this FTP problem anyway)

What usually happens, is that I will get an error (not a specific one, just one that is saying `Error installing nameofmodule`)

Recently though, I tried using a different user account with direct access to the folder (it being the user's home folder), and I am getting the folowing error

```
Warning: ftp_login(): Login incorrect. in FileTransferFTPExtension->connect() (line 59 of ..../includes/filetransfer/ftp.inc).
Failed to connect to the server. The server reports the following message:
Cannot log in to FTP server. Check username and password
```

I know the username and password are correct, I checked them more than a dozen times in terminal, however, I realized, that whenever I ftp into the server, I get an error if I use `ftp`, but I instead have to use `sftp`.

Is that what my problem is? If it is, how can I get Drupal to use `sftp` or `ssh` to transfer files instead of just `ftp`?

PS. If it helps, I am using the [OpenEnterprise 7.x-1.x-dev](http://drupal.org/project/openenterprise.) distribution of Drupal

Answer (score 1):

I would still like to be able to use `sftp`, but for now, I was able to set up `ssh` here's how I did it:

```
user$ sudo apt-get install libssh2-php
user$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

And now I can use the update manger with ssh, which works, for now......

Comment: SFTP is provided by the same php extension but there is no file transfer implementation for that provided by Drupal. The now deleted answer by Charlie S provided a link to a related issue: http://drupal.org/node/1018858